# Prevent TitledPane from opening when the grapich is clicked, in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx-2, graphic

I added a graphic (an icon) to a **TitledPane**, and set an `onMouseCliked` handler on it (to open a popup).

This event handler consume the event.
The problem is, when I click on the icon the popup is opened, but the **TitledPane** is also extended.

How could I prevent this?

```
public class MyPanel extends BorderPane{
    @FXML
    TitledPane titledPane;

    PopOver popOver;

    Text icon;

    public MyPanel(){

        //FXML injection

        popOver = new PopOver(new MyPane());

        icon = GlyphsDude.createIcon(FontAwesomeIcon.ANCHOR, "15");
        icon.setOnMouseClicked(this::onIconClicked);

        titledPane.setGraphic(icon);
    }

    public void onIconClicked(MouseEvent e){
        popOver.show(icon);
        e.consume();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your code, so that we can know what you have done?

Comment: I added the main elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

I was just consuming the `MOUSE_CLICKED` event, and the **TitledPane** is also handling `MOUSE_PRESSED`/`MOUSE_RELEASED` events.